# Corrupt files' contents, while FS is OK

Tags: linux, data-recovery, hard-drive, corruption

Looks like my USB HDD is old and corrupted:

```
rsync: read errors mapping "path/to/file.jpg": Input/output error (5)
```

Syslog:

```
kernel: [58927.940676] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
kernel: [58927.940683] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=invalid driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
kernel: [58927.940690] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
kernel: [58927.940696] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
kernel: [58927.940703] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 21 f2 df 00 00 08 00
kernel: [58927.940716] end_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 2224863
```

The strange thing is that FS is not spoilt: I can list all directories. However, reading the contents of about 10% files gives these errors. Adiitionally, most of small files are safe, however, large files are all spoilt (corruption threshold is ~5MB).

How can it be? What options do I have to investigate & rescue the files? Can it be a driver issue? I can't believe that HDD damage could miss the FS metadata!

P.S. this HDD is perfidious: I have always been doing backups, and it waited for the right moment to betray :-D

Comment: I'm sure you'd get more answers if you added a hat to your Gravatar. http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/2394/its-santa-time

Comment: THE RESULT: ddrescue did the job, managed to minimize the number of errors

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Listing the directories does not mean that the filesystem is ok, you're just viewing metadata (which is a *small* percent of a filesystem).

1. Create a backup of everything you can
2. Run a filesystem check (fsck)
3. Create another backup (in case fsck managed to save some more files)
4. Replace the disk

Comment: True. However, I can't believe such massive "damage" (whatever) could miss the metadata :) Already trying your suggestion, 10x!

Comment: Metadata isn't spread out over the file system, it's a reserved place on the disk (I can't remember where right now)

Comment: I have no idea what you wrote, but I like your hat.